# Cannot export table from PL/SQL developer having a column datatype as CLOB

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I need to export table having a column datatype as clob.

I need to have inserts scripts for that table. But I get following error when I try to export the table from PL/SQL developer

> Table XYZ contains one or more CLOB columns. Cannot export in SQL format, use PL/SQL Developer format instead

Is there a way I can export tables with CLOB column datatype using plain SQL scripts?

Comment: Which program do you use for exporting the data?

Comment: Need more information, what version of PL/SQL developer are you using? When you say "cannot"? Do you mean an error is shown or you can't find the option or something else...

Comment: I use Pl\SQL developer .

Comment: I need to have inserts scripts for that table , but I get following  error when I try to export the table from  Pl\SQL developer "Table XYZ contains one or more CLOB columns .
Cannot export in SQL format, use pl\SQL Developer format instead.
"

Answer (score 1):

I know that topic is old but maybe someone in future need this:
When You export a blob field use this

```
dbms_lob.substr( blob_field , 3999, 1) blob_field
```

where `blob_field` is your cblob

Answer (score 0):

As of the latestest version of SQLDeveloper you can try out xml export, this at least worked for me for CLOBs.